# Java : convert '2017-01-01 00:00:00' to '2017-01-01%2000:00:00'?

Tags: java, datetime

I need to pass '2017-01-01 00:00:00' to URl but I cannot as browsers represents `space character` with `%20` so I need to first convert `2017-01-01 00:00:00` to `2017-01-01%2000:00:00`. I can do this easily with splits and other methods but I am confused if java provides any built-in functions.

**UPDATE :**
thanks for valuable downvote and answers but `URLEncoder.encode` converts
`2017-01-01 00:00:00` to `2017-01-01+00%3A00%3A00` and not `2017-01-01%2000:00:00` and the link provided by downvoters didnot help either.
and I need to save this date on disk with `2017-01-01 00:00:00` and I don't want to decode it again and also on server there is strict regex check that only allows this specific formats and they didnt care to `urldecode` so my option is to use that give format i.e '2017-01-01%2000:00:00` and nothing else;
Sure I can do simple replace to whitespace with %20 and everything will be alright,then again I asked if there is any java function that only does this conversion like if we can provide a format and it gives us back the formatted value. This might sound stupid then again I asked if this is possible.

Comment: Is your input a pure `String` or a time object such as `Date` or `LocalDateTime`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) ...

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode("2017-01-01 00:00:00", "UTF-8")
```

Or alternatively use Apache HTTP Client's [URIBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) to build the complete URI, for example:

```
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder("http://host/endPoint");
uriBuilder.addParameter("parameterName", "2017-01-01 00:00:00");
String url = uriBuilder.toString();
```